# Разный дизайн google.com

Tags: вёрстка, google-chrome, internet-explorer, дизайн

Почему у меня(Internet Explorer 11), страница https://www.google.com выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а у моего друга(Chrome , не знаю какой, но не старый) вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чистки кэша на компьютере друга дизайн стал аналогичен моему. Что это значит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас разная ширина экрана. К тому же Google может экспериментировать с дизайном. Я например замечал изменение количества пунктов во всплывающей подсказке.

Comment: Ну а чистка кэша тут при чём?

Comment: Старая таблица стилей была закэширована браузером. Я вот сейчас посмотрел в отладчике - браузер загружает из кэша таблицу стилей с заголовком: max-age=31536000, т.е. 1 год. Ну понятное дело браузер может сам раньше загрузить заново новую версию файла, или файл можно переименовать, ну или кэш очистить.

Comment: Ага, теперь понятно. Спасибо за ответ!